# What's the meaning of this sentence that contains "the help of a guiding hand as far as the bathroom"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What's the meaning of this sentence?

> Much as I disliked the sponging process, and useless as it had been to suggest that the help of  a guiding hand as far as the bathroom could eliminate it, its failure to occur was highly disconcerting.

I run into it while studying for the FIRST exam.

Specifically I don't understand the "as far as the bathroom" part.

The sentence comes from a book called the "The Day of the Triffids".
Here you can see the sentence in context:

http://www.randomhouse.com/highschool/catalog/display.pperl?isbn=9780812967128&view=excerpt

Comment: Sentences like this are always easier to understand [in context](http://www.randomhouse.com/highschool/catalog/display.pperl?isbn=9780812967128&view=excerpt).

Comment: But not everyone else has the context, and they need to understand the sentence to write an answer, so it helps if you can [share that context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/168727/edit) in your post.

Comment: It means that if someone could guide the writer to the bathroom, he could wash himself, instead of needing to be sponged, but "useless" says that was an impossible suggestion.

Comment: Are you objecting to the absence of ***(only)*** *as far*?

Comment: (It also doesn't help that the parenthetical information is incomplete. It should read *could eliminate* ***this process*** in order to be a properly non-essential aside.)

Comment: I guess that the meaning must be the one mentioned by @WeatherVane    but I have never seen that sentence structure.

Comment: The section contained within commas is an *aside* or *digression* from the main idea of the sentence, which is that nobody came to wash him.

Comment: And because the extract is from "The Day Of The Triffids" the writer cannot see due to his eyes being covered, so cannot reach the bathroom alone. That was his salvation, because it saved him from going blind like most other people.

Comment: @JasonBassford OP omitted *it* at the end of the clause, which I have restored.

Comment: @StoneyB Ah! Much better.

Comment: @snailboat is absolutely right, *because* without the context, it's not completely clear whether the complaint is coming from the person being sponged, the person doing the sponging, or a third person who thinks the first should be able to manage it himself but has refused the offer of a helping hand to the bathroom :)

Answer (score 1):

"...the use of a guiding hand" is a complex way of saying "some help".
"...as far as the bathroom" indicates that he could not get that far by himself, and likely means the distance from his bed, or maybe chair, to the bathroom to wash.